# Does PreferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction in UISplitViewController have a limit?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to make a split view controller with the master view larger than the default one.

So I have subclassed it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction = .5;
}
```

The thing is that I can't divide 50/50 as its written on code... I only goes like 40% maybe...

No value less than 0.4 would work...

any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try setting `self.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth` to something large before setting the `preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction` property. This worked for me.

Per UISplitViewController Class Reference:

> The actual width of the primary view controller is constrained by the values in the `minimumPrimaryColumnWidth` and `maximumPrimaryColumnWidth` properties. The split view controller makes every other attempt to honor the width you specify but may change this value to accommodate the available space.

Comment: This worked for me. Can we get this as the accepted solution?

Comment: This worked for me, I'll put sample code in my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

For 50/50 do:

```
splitViewController.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = MAXFLOAT;
splitViewController.preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction = 0.5;
```

Setting these causes the view to load so do it in `viewDidLoad` rather than in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.